# move_uploaded_file() not working with valid ['tmp_name']

Tags: php, mysql

This baffles me. For some weird reason, move_uploaded_file() doesn't put the file into the directory, yet it returns a valid tmp_name and name. So in this case $file always = to false.

Anyway, can anyone point some problems with this code? It would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <?php
include 'realtydevkit.php';
session_start();
$name = $_FILES['yourlogo']['name'];
$tmpname = $_FILES['yourlogo']['tmp_name'];

if ($name) {
    $directory = $name;
    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $type = "logo";

    $file = move_uploaded_file($tmpname, $directory);

    if ($file == true) {    
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO usercontent
    (`userid`, `type`, `url`) VALUES
    ('$userid', '$type', '$directory')");
    echo 'Uploaded';
    echo "<img src='".$directory."'/>";
    } else {
    echo 'There was an error moving the file.';
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: your destination is just a file name, how about a path also.

Comment: Note: `$directory` is vulnerable to SQL injection...  `$directory = mysql_real_escape_string($name);`

Comment: Also note that you _must not_ use the direct unfiltered `$name` as a target filename for `move_uploaded_file()`. This opens you up to a great big [directory traversal attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack), allowing a user to write a file to many places on your filesystem.

Comment: Okay, I'm not worried about that right now. I just want this to work first. Because the point of the question was why the file didnt appear in the directory.

Comment: And the path doesn't need to be specified @Dagon the name is suffieicent because it will appear in the same folder. This is using the EXACT same code on a different server, which works perfectly fine. (Doesn't work on this server)

Comment: suffieicent but terrible practice.

Comment: Dude, this is just a temporary. I'm actually putting it in a parent directory for later use. I just wanted the actual code to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not checking `$_FILES['yourlogo']['error']`, either.

Here is what you check with an uploaded file:

1. Check `$_FILES['yourlogo']['error']`. If it is `UPLOAD_ERR_OK` (0), then proceed.
2. Check `is_uploaded_file($_FILES['yourlogo']['tmp_name'])`. If this fails, PHP doesn't know what went wrong, but it doesn't trust the file.
3. Assemble the destination path.
4. Use `move_uploaded_file()`.

If `move_uploaded_file()` errors, then PHP can't write the file at the destination. This is usually an invalid path or it doesn't have permissions.

Note that `$_FILES['yourlogo']['name']` is the name the file had on the uploader's PC. It shouldn't have any path information.

Comment: Okay helpful, but UPLOAD_ERR_OK came up as 0, the tmp_name appears when I echo it, and, the destination path is correct because it can just be the name and the root folder. If it's something related to permissions, how to allow access? It's a valid path so... I am using CENTOS and Parallels Plesk with PHP and MySQL

Comment: It needs to point to a directory the web server can write to. Also, try `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` early in the script. You might not be seeing the error it is trying to display. And look at http://au2.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php and http://au2.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: Yes, but, $name is the root directory and would work on another server with this code. How would I specifically point to a directory a web server can write to.

Comment: If your existing web server can normally write to root (`/`), then your existing web server is badly broken. And I'm not surprised this isn't working on your new server. To make the function work, just prepend a valid directory onto the front of `$name`. `/tmp` will work if you don't have a better location immediately available.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include 'realtydevkit.php';
session_start();
$name = $_FILES['yourlogo']['name'];
$tmpname = $_FILES['yourlogo']['tmp_name'];
if ($name) {
    $directory = $name;
    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $type = "logo";
    $file = move_uploaded_file($tmpname, "path of ur directore/".$directory);
    if ($file == true) {    
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO usercontent
    (`userid`, `type`, `url`) VALUES
    ('$userid', '$type', '$directory')");
    echo 'Uploaded';
    echo "<img src='".$directory."'/>";
    } 
   else 
   {
    echo 'There was an error moving the file.';
    }
}


?>
```